# Calculate skeleton joint's velocity SDK

Tags: c#, performance, sdk, kinect, skeleton-code

I'm developing a C# WPF fall detection application and I need to calculate the speed of the head joint and display it every 1/3 second (approximately). So if the person falls down ( The head position is too near from the floor ) I calculate the average speed of the last second to decide if it's a fall or a fall-like activity.

The problem is sometimes I get "non numeric" speed value and I'm not sure if my algorithm is calculating the speed correctly. Could you please help me?

Here's my code:

```
int init = 1;
double yHead;
int compteur=0;

void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (closing)
            {
                return;
            }


            using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrameData = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (skeletonFrameData == null) 
                {
                    return ;
                }

                skeletonFrameData.CopySkeletonDataTo(allSkeletons);
                skeletonFrameData.Dispose();

                Skeleton first = (from s in allSkeletons
                                  where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                                  select s).FirstOrDefault();

                if (first == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                compteur++; // Compteur de frames
                plane = skeletonFrameData.FloorClipPlane;

                GetCameraPoint(first, e);
                if  ((init==1)&&(first.Joints[JointType.Head].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked))
                {
                    yHead = calculerDistance(first.Joints[JointType.Head]);
                    init = 0;
                    Di = yHead;
                    Ti = skeletonFrameData.Timestamp;
                }
                else{

                    if(init == 0)

                    if (fall == false)
                    {

                        yHead = calculerDistance(first.Joints[JointType.Head]);

                        Dj = yHead; Tj = skeletonFrameData.Timestamp;
                        Vi = Math.Abs(1000 * ((Dj - Di) / (Tj - Ti)));

                        if (compteur == 8)
                        { 
                            speed.Content = "Speed=" + Vi.ToString("0.##") + "m/s";             
                            compteur = 0;
                        }
                        posit.Content = "Head position: " + yHead.ToString("0.##");
                        Di = Dj;
                        Ti = Tj;

                    }
                }

            }

        }


        double calculerDistance(Joint joint)
        {
            float A = plane.Item1;
            float B = plane.Item2;
            float C = plane.Item3;
            float D = plane.Item4;

            float x = (joint.Position.X) * A;
            float y = (joint.Position.Y) * B;
            float z = (joint.Position.Z) * C;

            double distance = Math.Abs((x + y + z + D) / Math.Sqrt((A * A) + (B * B) + (C * C)));
            return distance;
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you debug with test cases?

Comment: What does it mean "test cases"?